# Implement Malbolge's "crazy" operator

Tags: code-golf, number

One of many unique features of the [Malbolge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Malbolge) programming language is its highly unintuitive `OP` operator, referred to only as "op" in the documentation and source code but popularly known as the "crazy" operator. As described by Ben Olmstead, the creator of the language, in its documentation: "*don't look for pattern, it's not there*."

op is a "tritwise" operator -- it operates on corresponding ternary digits of its two arguments. For each trit (ternary bit), the result of op is given by the following lookup table:

```
           a
op(a,b)  0 1 2
       +-------
     0 | 1 0 0
   b 1 | 1 0 2
     2 | 2 2 1
```

For example, to calculate `op(12345, 54321)`, first write out both numbers in ternary and then look up each pair of trits in the table:

```
   0121221020   (12345_3)
op 2202111220   (54321_3)
--------------
   2202220211   (54616_3)
```

The last important point is that all values in Malbolge are 10 trits wide, so input values should be padded with zeroes to a width of 10. (For instance, `op(0, 0)` is `1111111111` in ternary.)

Your task is to take two integers 0 ≤ `a`, `b` < 59049 as input, and output the integer value of `op(a,b)`.

Test cases (in the format `a b op(a,b)`):

```
0 0 29524
1 2 29525
59048 5 7
36905 2214 0
11355 1131 20650
12345 54321 54616
```

Here is a [reference implementation](https://tio.run/##hZLtboIwFIb/exVvXExgdhtfVQi6G3H@MOBHzVYMYKIxXDs7rUUZRpac0NNznryn7Uvytk2S@kXI5PuYrjErylRk77vP@igLsZXrFMUuy0tkBwud0ol1K2fYg8sA3bLAHA7DPqZWUa5KkSDJZFF2uUO04EvMiQIucBkihpCWqUfJhE9cVP9JZItoSdGI6K8SCxh8HSTn6DAJKtaBeNPzbkkb4poIdPtKmORRqT1uSjeg6B93hcL@caGOaRsy4uyemAM8QiG7J@YAbShsiFtiDtBA2oFNlsPCXtka0zIDp2U8JvcVIjCekxFnfChH90uMQKac/mzxet0otXxdHnNJggJ2PKhqIUv8rIS0bGPgIafSxhqO0i85ZOpXVG9q2/GTrvLkeZdHTkBX488JfxI5dGfPc4OeIa7PlXeu7/ZAnh@oBwx8T1NV/Qs) (copied directly from the Malbolge source code).

Comment: can this be answered in Malboge? ;)

Comment: I guess Malbolge is a good golfing language now!

Comment: For what it's worth, `54616_3` doesn't mean "this other thing is the decimal number 54616, but represented as base three". It means "Read `54616` as base 3". Which, of course, you can't do (there are digits that Valve can't count to in there). It'd still probably be just as clear if you got rid of the `_3` entirely, and more accurate.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I guess just using the operator in Malbolge would fall under the standard loophole. Reimplementing it using different code would be okay.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann No, **that's not a loophole**.

Answer (score 45):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>99</s> <s>98</s> 96 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); golfing `19683` to `L'䳣'`.
- Saved two bytes; golfing `108609` to `L''`.

```c
M,a,l,b,o;L(g,e){for(o=b=L'䳣',l=0;o/=2.4;b/=3)M=g/b,g%=b,a=e/b,e%=b,l+=b*(L''>>M+6*a+M&3);g=l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5NToQwGAbgtZyCjEHaoSP9RbH5xgvAbpZuKFMICYKZuJuMiddwZzyCV/IA3gBbwCbN@@ZJ@7X1rq3raSpJRXpiyKgL1BKLz814QiMYKOKf76@Y9ED1mAK/ldqkIHAJbWpIG4EhFVhXra99AmaLivj34/M93u/LJNtWSXkjsG6h15fp@mibbrDhAVXuLYtfTt3w2qBNpI6h32/7OQDmQFGNn4YN8WcLfwMTu5adfWSUPzCWYR08V92A8Dm4OqDQLUrCNXiuuMT/zhbni6vZVU7l/eJqibvZRZZTD5wzuY6bnTGhvLt04zjN1OpcSOdKCs58ZO5jwWX6Aw)

Comment: I like the naming scheme!

Answer (score 30):

## JavaScript (ES7), 56 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b,k=9)=>~k&&(a%3|b%3<<9|8)**2%82%3+3*f(a/3,b/3,k-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc3RCoIwGAXg@57CG2Uzze3/95sD7V2maZTiIqMr6dVtpRDogcO5@eDczMsM1eN6f8a9PdfT1BTMRGXUFpoXp3cbBMz4OJY@5rkeMx6G4Gfg4x7DhpkEo9K1jSWfKtsPtqsPnb2whnkuIvJ@w7mXJB5oArXbKjkr@CtaKdJCZbOiWR1XAlMtyAkAqWYhVkJKpK9wK5cnkdJGASqnSCEsilQq0@kD)

### How?

Given \$a\$ and \$b\$ in \$[0..2]\$, we compute:

$$f(a,b)=((a+512b+8)^2 \bmod 82) \bmod 3$$

Leading to:

```
 a | b | 512b | a + 512b |  + 8 | squared | MOD 82 | MOD 3
---+---+------+----------+------+---------+--------+-------
 0 | 0 |    0 |      0   |    8 |      64 |   64   |   1                  a
 1 | 0 |    0 |      1   |    9 |      81 |   81   |   0                0 1 2
 2 | 0 |    0 |      2   |   10 |     100 |   18   |   0              +-------
 0 | 1 |  512 |    512   |  520 |  270400 |   46   |   1            0 | 1 0 0
 1 | 1 |  512 |    513   |  521 |  271441 |   21   |   0    -->   b 1 | 1 0 2
 2 | 1 |  512 |    514   |  522 |  272484 |   80   |   2            2 | 2 2 1
 0 | 2 | 1024 |   1024   | 1032 | 1065024 |    8   |   2
 1 | 2 | 1024 |   1025   | 1033 | 1067089 |   23   |   2
 2 | 2 | 1024 |   1026   | 1034 | 1069156 |   40   |   1
```

#### Function choice

There are several other possible candidate functions of the form:

$$f_{k,c,p,m}(a,b)=((a+kb+c)^p \bmod m) \bmod 3$$

One of the shortest ones being:

$$f(a,b)=((a+5b+2)^4 \bmod 25) \bmod 3$$

But the good thing about \$(a+512b+8)\$ is that it can be performed with bitwise operators, thus implicitly discarding the decimal parts of \$a\$ and \$b\$. This is why we can simply divide them by \$3\$ without rounding between each iteration.

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (a, b,            // given the input integers a and b
           k = 9) =>  // and starting with k = 9
  ~k &&               // if k is not equal to -1:
    ( a % 3           //   compute (a mod 3)
      | b % 3 << 9    //   add 512 * (b mod 3)
      | 8             //   add 8
    ) ** 2            //   square the result
    % 82              //   apply modulo 82
    % 3               //   apply modulo 3, leading to crazy(a % 3, b % 3)
    + 3 * f(          //   add 3 times the result of a recursive call with:
      a / 3,          //     a / 3  \__ no rounding required
      b / 3,          //     b / 3  /   (see 'Function choice')
      k - 1           //     k - 1
    )                 //   end of recursive call
```

Comment: I think `(1581093>>b%3*2+a%3*8&3)` saves a whole byte!

Comment: @Neil Unfortunately,  I'm passing `a/3` and `b/3` without rounding. That would fail because of that.

Comment: Interesting how you found a pattern which does not exist.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `k = 9 ... => ~k && ...` to `k = 10 ... => k && ...` ?

Comment: @Falco No, it's neither shorter nor more efficient in any way. I'd just tend to prefer 0-indexed stuff, so I'd rather mimic `for(k=9;k>=0;k--)` than `for(k=10;k>=1;k--)`.

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

#### Code:

```
3Tm+3Bø5+3m5(^3%3β
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fOCRX29jp8A5TbeNcU404Y1Xjc5v@/482NDI2MdVRMDUxNjKMBQA)

#### Algorithm Explanation

In order to get the number padded with zeroes, we need to add **59049** to both numbers (because 59049 in ternary is **10000000000**). We do not have to leave out the leading **1** as \$(1, 1) \rightarrow 0\$. We convert the numbers from decimal to ternary and join each pair as each own number.

For example, for input **12345** and **54321**, these get mapped to:

$$
\begin{array}
& 12345 \rightarrow & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
54321 \rightarrow & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{array}
$$

Which gives the following list of joined integers:

$$
11, 2, 12, 20, 12, 21, 21, 11, 2, 22, 0
$$

These integers need to be mapped by the given lookup table in the OP. The formula we currently use that maps these numbers to their corresponding trits (\$0 \rightarrow 1, 10 \rightarrow 0, \dots\$) is:

$$
f(x) = \left((x + 5)^3 \oplus -5\right) \text{ mod }3
$$

Whereas \$\oplus\$ denotes the bitwise **xor** function.

Eventually after mapping this function on the list of joined integers, we treat this resulting list as a number represented in base 3 and convert it from base 3 to decimal.

#### Code Explanation

```
3Tm+                  # Add 59049 to pad the ternary number with zeroes.
    3B                # Convert to base 3.
      ø               # Zip the list to get each joined integer.
       5+             # Add 5 to each element.
         3m           # Raise each element to the power of 3.
           5(^        # XOR each element with -5.
              3%      # Modulo each element with 3.
                3β    # Convert from base 3 to decimal.
```

Comment: Can `3Tm+3Bø19sm74%3%3β` be golfed?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice find! It does however seem impossible to golf it any further without using some other kind of black magic formula.

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```r
function(a,b,x=3^(9:0))30801%/%x[a%/%x%%3*3+b%/%x%%3+1]%%3%*%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ0mnwtY4TsPSykBT09jAwsBQVV@1IjoRRKqqGmsZaydBmdqGsUBSVUu14n@ahqGRsYmpjqmJsZGh5n8A)

*Thanks to [JAD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59530/jad) for some <s>black magic</s> golfing tricks and -2 bytes!*

`30801`, when converted to a 10-trit ternary integer, is `1120020210` which just adds a trailing zero to the operation table, when read down the columns. Then we convert the ternary digits of `a` and `b` elementwise into an integer and use that as an index into the ternary digits of `30801`.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ0mnwtY4TsPSykBT09jAwsBQVV@1IjoRRKqqGmsZaydBmdqGsUBSVUu14n@ahqGRsYmpjqmJsZGh5n8A) Yay for operator precedence!

Comment: Yeah, this way, you first index `x` using `[.*]`. Then all the `%any%` operations happen. The fun part is that if you see `30801%/%x%%3` as `f=function(x)30801%/%x%%3`, that `f(x[index]) == (f(x))[index]`. Saving the braces :)

Comment: @JAD fascinating! And as I comment above, basically black magic.

Comment: I'll happily admit that this took a lot of fiddling :P

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```c
f(a,b,i,r){for(r=0,i=59049;i/=3;)r+=(108609>>a/i%3*2+b/i%3*6&3)*i;i=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5dC8IwDHy2v6IISrtF7Mc6Nkr9Jb50k408OKWIL2O/vaYqhNzlckcynuZxzHkSEQZASHKdHkmkoACD61XTezwH62Wqg9Cqa1V/ucQzHmxl6uGL7dHKCj2G5Lf8fuCNzwKXF4/ACwySrWz3TMQnsT/cOFWgdl32UDwD8HKcfNKzjbGSuUdcxDc3CwVc0YaYBm5@rDzWAXe/yba9crQzuvkbtXUkEOi/YGxDgmusKcqWPw)

### Breakdown

The truth table

```c
           a
op(a,b)  0 1 2
       +-------
     0 | 1 0 0
   b 1 | 1 0 2
     2 | 2 2 1
```

Can be thought of as a 3x3 array, where a is the column, and b is the row. Transforming that into a one-dimensional list gives us 100102221. To save space we avoid lists and strings and make it into a number instead. To do that, we flip the order and transform every trit into a 2-bit number. Glue them together and we have a binary number we can "index" into by shifting to the right by `2 * (b * 3 + a)` and masking:

```c
 1 0 0 1 0 2 2 2 1
 1 2 2 2 0 1 0 0 1
011010100001000001
```

Next, we massage the expression using the power of operation precedence to become the abomination above.

<s>3^9 = 19683 so that is a good loop limit. Since we multiply the counter by 3 each time, we can write the limit as `2e4` instead. Also we save ourselves the bother of `pow()` or similar.</s>

On second thought, let's start at 3^10 and work downwards with a pre-loop divide-and-test.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 108 bytes

```hs
2%2=1
_%2=2
0%_=1
2%1=2
_%_=0
g=take 10.map(`mod`3).iterate(`div`3)
(foldr((.(3*)).(+))0.).(.g).zipWith(%).g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcc7DsMgEEXRnlVQBGkmkUaAa9aREpD4GBls5KAU2Tyhefe83X@OWOucWmijmF2rmRR2WQu1bJcly2b4I3IlqfkOrl3BbUhlxNuPCC6U7/osGUhXDTcAwfZEJHghSlqljPQr/V3GDgIpz@bLafpdzvFIXHE9/w)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>41</s> 25 bytes

*9 bytes saved thanks to @Adám*

```apl
3⊥(b⊤6883)[3⊥⍉⎕⊤⍨3,b←9⍴3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@Gz/qWqqR9KhriZmFhbFmNIj7qLcTqAgo9Kh3hbFOElCt5aPeLcax/4Ea/iuAQQGXgYIBF4xtpGAIZ5sqmFoamFgg5IwMTRSMzSwNTOFChobGhgpAwhQhZGpibAQUMzI2MQUA)

Comment: Takes inputs in reversed order, 25 bytes: [`3⊥(b⊤6883)[3⊥⍉⎕⊤⍨3,b←9⍴3]`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@Gz/qWqqR9KhriZmFhbFmNIj7qLcTqAgo9Kh3hbFOElCt5aPeLcax/4Ea/iuAQQGXgYIBF4xtpGAIZ5sqmFoamFgg5IwMTRSMzSwNTOFChobGhgpAwhQhZGpibAQUMzI2MQUA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám thanks! that's some neat stuff. I guess I've gone a bit rusty :P

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>23</s>  18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (rearrange `3*⁵¤` to `⁵3*`)

```
⁵3*+b3Zḅ3ị⁽½Ṡb3¤ḅ3
```

A monadic link accepting a list of two integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41ZjLe0k46iHO1qNH@7uftS499DehzsXJBkfWgIS@v//v6GRsYmpjoKpibGRIQA)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41ZjLe0k46iHO1qNH@7uftS499DehzsXJBkfWgIS@n90z@H2R01r3IDY/f//6GgDHQWDWB2FaEMdBSMQbWppYGKho2AKYhubWRqYAsWNDE3ASgyNTYFcIGUI5hoZmwC5pibGRoaxsQA).

`⁹*%733%3` is a byte longer than `ị⁽½Ṡb3¤` :(

#### How?

```
⁵3*+b3Zḅ3ị⁽½Ṡb3¤ḅ3 - Link: [a, b]      e.g. [11355,1131]
⁵                  - literal ten            10
 3                 - literal three          3
  *                - exponentiation         59049
   +               - addition (vectorises)  [70404,60180]
     3             - literal three          3
    b              - to base (vectorises)   [[1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0],[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,0]]
      Z            - transpose              [[1,1],[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[0,0]]
        3          - literal three          3
       ḅ           - from base (vectorises) [4,0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,0]
               ¤   - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
          ⁽½Ṡ      -   literal 3706         3706
              3    -   literal three        3
             b     -   to base              [1,2,0,0,2,0,2,1]
         ị         - index into             [0,1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1,1]
                 3 - literal three          3
                ḅ  - from base              20650
```

---

Also 18: `⁵3*+b3ZḌ19*%74%3ḅ3` (uses a magic-formula after getting the pair-wise trits of converting from base ten then taking 19 to that power, modulo 74, modulo 3 to get the required trits of the output - found using a search in Python)

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R41ZjLe0k46iHO1qNH@7uftS499DehzsXJBkfWgIS@v//v6GRsYmpjoKpibGRIQA) (note: there should really be a "prepend `y` `0`s"built-in)

Comment: Ugh I thought that looked awkward. Thanks!

Comment: Many things look awkward, sometimes you have to get used to them. :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>79</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for his formula (-2 bytes).

```python
f=lambda a,b,i=9:i+1and(a%3+b%3*5+2)**4%25%3+f(a/3,b/3,i-1)*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BCsMwDEPv@wpfCknqsTiOx1roxySUssCWltLLvj5zezDyExLafsd7raG1Zfqkb54TJMxYpmEsPaU6m9Rxnzt20gfrXOyCqLGY9GDMeuVO1nFb1l2LkKFUMB7BWwRDCOFUGXx8Icj583Pwon6geEWIRVGFLgwcFSVyIDveALa91AN0DrNtfw)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
((3 3$d 30801){~{@,.)&.(d=.(10$3)&#:)
```

Explanation:

```
((3 3$d 30801){~{@,.)&.(d=.(10$3)&#:)   
                       (d=.(10$3)&#:)   convert to 10 trits, and name this function as d
                     &.                 ... which is done on both args and inverted on the result
                {@,.                    make boxed indices: 1 2 3 4 {@,. 5 6 7 8  ->  1 5 ; 2 6 ; 3 7 ; 4 8
              {~                        index out of a lookup table
 (3 3$d 30801)                          reusing the trits conversion function to make the table
```

Ended up being relatively readable, tbh.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! [Here](https://tio.run/##LYwxCsMwDEV3n0K0IbEhCMmySmIw9C5NTenSIWNor@7aOIPQ@0/iv0veEwJBBCrWCsiwgdBC7I7fcZ/RjWi3hJZpEDdeoyvOXBCmnHCCGb4R8m7M8/H61JJcpzNX9h11pbDUqD3KbSVtV8/h/GXRZurm03gJzWgQz@UP) is a test-suite - I stole the wrapping code from Galen Ivanov's answer.

Comment: Welcom to PPCG!
Nice solution! [Here](https://tio.run/##LYwxCsMwDEV3n0K0IbEhCMmySmIw9C5NTenSIWNor@7aOIPQ@0/iv0veEwJBBCrWCsiwgdBC7I7fcZ/RjWi3hJZpEDdeoyvOXBCmnHCCGb4R8m7M8/H61JJcpzNX9h11pbDUqD3KbSVtV8/h/GXRZurm03gJzWgQz@UP) is a TIO link to it.

Comment: [30](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsMwDATvfoVoQhJDEJJllcRgyF@amtJLDzmG9uuujXPa2ZH2ndMREQgCUJ72TWghPn/S4Yx2wD3ixNSLHbqQrbkhjCniCDN8A6TDmOfj9SnrBNSQC7qGupJfStVW5b6S1qtjf/2yaDUl@TJOfDXqxXH@Aw)

Comment: [28](https://tio.run/##LYtBDoMwDATveYVVKkgkZNlxXEEkXlM1qnrhwJHC10OicNrZsfeX07YgEESgLDQR2/2UDv/R9Wgt01Nc30U3ZmceCENacIARjghpM@bz/q5lm4AackHfUGcKU6naqrxm0nr1HO5fFq2mJN/GS6hGg3jOFw)

Comment: @FrownyFrog nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
Ｉ↨³⮌⭆χ§200211⁺∨﹪÷θＸ³ι³¦⁴﹪÷ηＸ³ι³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYy9CsIwGEVfJXT6ChHy18lJ69KhWHQUh9AEGwiJJmn07WPEsRcOXDiXOy8yzF7aUqZgXIJexgRHGTVwjC4661DrNVX3GOUTKMHokAan9AcaRgijtMFosmuEc4DRq9V6GFw6mWyUhld1/q3D78y0LUa8Iiqb5bJd/rMv5UYZFx1GneCM3ssu2y8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     χ                          Predefined variable 10
    ⭆                           Map over implicit range and join
                    ι        ι  Current index
                  Ｘ³       Ｘ³   Power of 3
                 θ              Input `a`
                          η     Input `b`
                ÷        ÷      Integer divide
               ﹪     ³  ﹪     ³ Modulo by 3
              ∨       ¦⁴        Replace zero ternary digit of `a` with 4
             ⁺                  Add
      §200211                   Index into literal string `200211`
   ⮌                            Reverse
 ↨³                             Convert from base 3
Ｉ                               Cast to string
                                Implicitly print
```

Alternative solution, also 31 bytes:

```
Ｉ↨³Ｅ↨⁺Ｘ³χθ³§200211⁺∨ι⁴§↨⁺Ｘ³χη³κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxOFXDWEfBN7EAwg7IKS3WCMgvTy0CCRsaaOooFAKxMRA7lnjmpaRWaCgZGRgYGRoq6SiAFfsXaWTqKJggKcBlUAbUoGxNELD@/z/a0MjYxFRHwdTE2Mgw9r9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code.

```
        χ                  χ    Predefined variable 10
      Ｘ³                 Ｘ³     Power of 3 i.e. 59049
         θ                      Input `a`
                            η   Input `b`
     ⁺                  ⁺       Sum
    ↨     ³            ↨     ³  Convert to base 3
   Ｅ                            Map over elements
                    ι           Current ternary digit of `a`
                   ∨ ⁴          Replace zero with 4
                      §       κ Index into ternary digits of `b`
                  ⁺             Add
           §200211              Index into literal string `200211`
 ↨³                             Convert from base 3
Ｉ                               Cast to string
                                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>90</s> 87 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,A='':f(a/3,b/3,'100102221'[a%3+b%3*3]+A)if a+b else int(A.rjust(10,'1'),3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7PDoIwDMbP8hS9mG3S6LoyoyYceA7CYYsSMYgE8ODTz8Kh@frr32/8Lc/P4FJqyz684z1AwIhVqdSt1eHEGCUUWUvWOUeqDnvO454P3OSV6VoIeYRHPz@gGxZdHafXd140WdlRBtmk9jOtJ6UNtbYI1iBoQnCr@qstLgh@zfl8tV7qjopthNgLitCGjgtBX7Aj09yy3TjJw82s@MRospT@)

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é╨¼aûé∟ç⌂zπb![5┬◘«╜‼╞♠
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82d0ac6196821c877f7ae362215b35c208aebd13c606&i=[0,0]%0A[1,2]%0A[59048,5]%0A[36905,2214]%0A[11355,1131]%0A[12345,54321]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
3/(3\10267)@3/+(10#3)\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrNCoJQEIbhfVcxUAslwvk5c8wzm@5DBdsYoRiICyXq1k9qmw@ej7e7DI8hxjZIlkhFyD5Pb5KdE8KjpFWcwvtULt8xtDBb8@osadr7s7fZFhvT@nOYSgQ0LpRdvYKAd@gGLdBdQS3fIL5ABWZyhntJogrrkjF6/X8sTkGdMJk6T76OPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,l=10{l>0?6883.digits(3)[8-b%3*3-a%3]*3**(10-l)+f[a/3,b/3,l-1]:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUzdCoMgGL3fU@wmKPfZ1E/DBrUHES@U1QgcxKqLUT27sy7OP5zv4n@xbyJtHXgIDWdraNmz0hrL1/Ae5inHwmjqMyRIXYaWICE5ZzQUt964O4JPCJTbB9vjuMzT1RgGzMLFcBCHqJpJDeqwWNVMgRBcnjtHpSAxP5NAqUBJFNza8uPGdeu23nQmfXUmdXv8Aw)

Decomposes `a` and `b` recursively until we get 10 digits of each. `6883` gives the flattened ternary table (reversed). Reconstructs from ternary to decimal by multiplying by `3**(10-l)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Cjam, 31 bytes

```
{{3bA0e[\}2*.{3*+"100102221"=}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7raOMnRIDU6ptZIS6/aWEtbydDAwNDAyMjIUMm2tvb/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 43 bytes

```
3#.((3 3$t 6883){~<@,~"0)&(_10{.t=.3&#.inv)
```

It can certainly be golfed further.

### Explanation:

```
                         &(               ) - for both arguments
                                t=.3&#.inv  - convert to base 3 (and name the verb t)
                           _10{.            - pad left with zeroes
   (              <@,~"0)                   - box the zipped pairs (for indexing)
    (3 3$t 6883)                            - the lookup table
                {~                          - use the pairs as indeces in the table
3#.                                         - back to decimal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwDIbvfYqwydbCCE3Tjm5Y8E08iEU96GHDy3CvXlu6Q8j3fwn/K8UlIGiYQSduUUoGPq0wes9q28@XYW@06uSV9IZrQO5afL6/KinRIPQxYA8D/GaIixD32@OTq2KeypTZVHSTtj5HVyOPk3blasgev8SumLzpMIZtMc6yofQH)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) <s>26 25</s> 24 bytes

*Saved 1 byte, thanks to @ErikTheOutgolfer*

*Save another byte, inspired by @JonathanAllan's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167700/41020)*

```
im@j3422 3id3Cm.[0Tjd3Q3
```

Input is a 2 element list `[a,b]`. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=im%40j3422%203id3Cm.%5B0Tjd3Q3&input=%5B12345%2C54321%5D&debug=0), or verify all test cases [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=QE%0Aim%40j3422%203id3Cm.%5B0Tjd3Q3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C0%5D%0A29524%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A29525%0A%5B59048%2C5%5D%0A7%0A%5B36905%2C%202214%5D%0A0%0A%5B11355%2C1131%5D%0A20650%0A%5B12345%2C54321%5D%0A54616&debug=0&input_size=2).

```
im@j3422 3id3Cm.[0Tjd3Q3   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
              m       Q    Map each element d of the input using:
                   jd3       Convert to base 3
               .[0T          Pad to length 10 with 0's
             C             Transpose
 m                         Map each element d of the above using:
   j3422 3                   The lookup table [1,1,2,0,0,2,0,2]
  @                          Modular index into the above using
          id3                Convert d to base 10 from base 3
i                      3   Convert to base 10 from base 3, implicit print
```

Comment: `.T` can be `C`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

Getting the ball rolling on Japt's run as [language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16592/58974) - I fully expect to be outgolfed on this!

Takes input in reverse order as an integer array (i.e., `[b,a]`).

```
ms3 ùTA y_n3 g6883ì3Ãì3
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bXMzIPlUQSB5X24zIGc2ODgz7DPD7DM&input=WzU0MzIxLDEyMzQ1XQ)

```
ms3 ùTA y_n3 g6883ì3Ãì3      :Implicit input of array U=[b,a]
m                            :Map
 s3                          :  Convert to base-3 string
    ù                        :Left pad each
     T                       :  With zero
      A                      :  To length 10
        y                    :Transpose
         _                   :Map
          n3                 :  Convert from base-3 string to decimal
             g               :  Index into
              6883ì3         :    6883 converted to a base-3 digit array
                    Ã        :End map
                     ì3      :Convert from base-3 digit array to decimal
```

Comment: spoiler alert: Shaggy did not get outgolfed.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 77 bytes (17 instrs + 9 data bytes)

```
00000000: e303000a f4040010 e3020000 e3050001  ẉ¤¡½ṡ¥¡Ñẉ£¡¡ẉ¦¡¢
00000010: 25030301 1d000003 fe060006 1d010103  %¤¤¢ø¡¡¤“©¡©ø¢¢¤
00000020: feff0006 28060606 200606ff 80060406  “”¡©(©©© ©©”⁰©¥©
00000030: 18060506 20020206 28050505 5b03fff5  ð©¦© ££©(¦¦¦[¤”ṫ
00000040: f8030000 01010200 00020002 01        ẏ¤¡¡¢¢£¡¡£¡£¢
```

```
malop   SET   $3,10         // i = 10
        GETA  $4,1F         // oparr = {1,1,2,0,0,2,0,2,1}
        SET   $2,0          // r = 0
        SET   $5,1          // p = 1
0H      SUB   $3,$3,1       // loop: i--
        DIV   $0,$0,3
        GET   $6,rR         // x:xr = x /% 3
        DIV   $1,$1,3
        GET   $255,rR       // y:yr = y /% 3
        2ADDU $6,$6,$6
        ADD   $6,$6,$255
        LDB   $6,$4,$6      // j = oparr[xr * 3 + yr]
        MUL   $6,$5,$6      // j *= p
        ADD   $2,$2,$6      // r += j
        2ADDU $5,$5,$5      // p *= 3
        PBNZ  $3,0B         // if(i) goto loop
        POP   3,0           // return r
1H      BYTE  1,1,2,0,0,2,0,2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 102 bytes

```perl
sub t{map{("@_"%3,$_[0]/=3)[0]}0..9}@a=t$_;@b=t<>}{$\=(1,1,2,0,0,2,0,2,1)[(3*pop@a)+pop@b]+$\*3while@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcXdCoIwAEDh@54iZMGm0/bjLqIWe4GeQEU2GDUwHbroQvbqLYvD4fN2HkRKy8vsw/rUfoWZ6rMDx6BvSHeUHG1EUlWnqLQMoD8rI8PlGlfQSkgxxQyTLfafogby3E9eaVT8MF0B2py/H26wSqdEGa/FTtSc0c/kg5vGJZU3NwZ7t3Mq/Rc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>75</s> <s>72</s> 60 bytes

```
(d=IntegerDigits)[6883,3][[{1,3}.d[#,3,10]+1]]~FromDigits~3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsIwFEV3vyIgiOJTkry82A7ZRHDoF4QMRUvN0Co1W2l/PUZTcLpwzr23q8Oj6ergb3WsmInbu7n2oWmb4exbH947q4sCAZ21owCcjne7BgTB3V44N1@GZ5eLM27iWNmRA@OTY8YwWZJUsGLVd8nkH1KGVHJVAKMsTsB@FHXJKdWlUFnw5UIgJZ5CLE9cE19GQqJKkhTKxZLSQk8xHl6D78MH)

un-golfed version:

```
M[{a_, b_}] := 
  FromDigits[{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1}[[
    IntegerDigits[a, 3, 10] + 3*IntegerDigits[b, 3, 10] + 1
  ]], 3];
```

Both `a` and `b` are converted to ten-trit lists, then used pairwise as a 2D index into a lookup table of numbers `{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1}`. The result is again interpreted as a ten-trit list and converted back to integer form.

The lookup table is coded as `IntegerDigits[6883,3]`, which is short because we are recycling the `IntegerDigits` symbol.